# Custom radio icon alignment issue, looks like oval

Tags: html, css

I am making a custom radio button using div. But I have alignment issue. The radio button looks like oval instead of circle.

Here is my html code.

```
<div class="customRadioBtn">
  <div class="radio_wrap selected">
    <span class="radioDot"></span>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Here is the css

```
.customRadioBtn {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.customRadioBtn .radio_wrap {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 #d4d4d4;
}

.customRadioBtn .radio_wrap .radioDot {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: #5f4ebf;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
    transition: all .2s ease;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Here is how it looks

[image]

Here is the link to fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/z8muoseb/1/

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: set `width: 16px` and `height: 16px` to `.radio_wrap`

Answer (score 0):

May be the height and width issue

```
.customRadioBtn .radio_wrap {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work with 15px? Is there any specific issue?

Comment: Because you are using '15px' and '10px' which is un-even always use, even or odd values for setting parent and child divs like 2 4, 6 12 etc

Comment: Is there any guideline for which states this?

Comment: Yes some how but it depends on your typography as well In your case may be i change the typography that ratio will work